# Unix Script to FTP a file from server to mainframe

Tags: unix, ftp, mainframe

I have coded a script like below to send file to mainframe. But it didn't work please help
$1 is the file name in the server
$2 is mainframe dataset name.
the file names are correct ..that i can see in the email that send out after the process.
what is wrong with this ?

```
function ftp_mainframe
    {     mainFrame=mvs.xxx.com    
      ftp -i -v $mainFrame <<END    
  quote SITE lrecl=400 recfm=fb blksize=27600    
      echoToEmailFile "COMMENT" "$1 $2"    
      put $1 $2   
      quit   
    END
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running the above manually from the command line? Also, no where do i see you specifying a userid or password

Comment: it FTP'ed but it looks like it ftp'ed to HFS server.. didn't push to mainframe

Comment: If, by "HFS server" you mean "Hierarchical File System" then that _is_ the mainframe - it's just a different file system _on_ the mainframe.  This is important because it rules out authentication problems.  Please confirm.

Comment: If the data is getting to the mainframe but as an HFS dataset, then the "logon" being used is for unix-on-the-mainframe, not a logon for z/OS which would allow the data to arrive where you expect it. It looks as though you must be using "anonymous" (by default), as I also can't see where the login in specified, and if anonymous  exists it'll not be on z/OS.

Comment: @Bill, Unix System Services is an ESM privilege, same authentication credentials as for TSO, CICS, IMS, or any other ESM privilege (at least that's how we do it). z/Linux is, of course, a separate operating system, but I would expect "HFS" to refer to USS and not z/Linux.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks. I was concerned about where the id and password were entered. Anonymous was the only thing I could thing which would not need it. However, I guess END is a file containing the id and password. The answer should be simple. Id given is a USS (possibly z/Linux) not for z/OS. Wherever the file ended up, that's where the id used logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a member to a dataset you need to surround it with '. So the put command would be something like

```
put test.txt 'QUAL1.QUAL2(MEMNAME)'
```

Comment: When you say, "i tried now" please show us _exactly_ what you tried and any error messages that appeared, either in your client session or in the mainframe operlog.